# query eloquent and sql

Tags: php, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I´m trying to create query that return "Number of companies that belong to the census" with laravel Eloquent or DB::raw()

i think that my query it´s `select count(censosEmpresas.empresa_cif) from censosEmpresas groupBy codigoCenso` similar it´s in mysql. My problem it´s that i´m using resolve with GraphQL and laravel and i don´t know if it´s correct because to extract this data i´m in activity table that it has a relationship with censos with column `censo_id` and censo has a relationship with `censosEmpresas` with column `codigoCenso`. i think that to build this query i need `leftJoin` and i´m building my query so:

```
public function actividadesPorAplicacionConEmpresasCount($root, array $args, $context, $info)
{
    $actividadId = $args["aplicacion_id"];
    //$countEmpresas = CensosEmpresas::groupBy('empresa_cif')->select('codigoCenso', \DB::raw('count(*) as totalEmpresas'))->where('codigoCenso', $aplicacionId)->get();
    $countEmpresas = Actividad::select(count('censosEmpresas.empresa_cif'))
                                ->leftJoin('censos', 'id', 'actividades.censo_id')
                                ->leftJoin('censosEmpresas', 'id', 'censosEmpresas.codigoCenso')
                                ->where('censosEmpresas.codigoCenso', $actividadId)
                                ->groupBy('codigoCenso');

    return $countEmpresas;
}
```

but this, return en mi console:

```
debugMessage: 
"count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, string given"
```

I don´t know if i´m building my query correctly. My database structure it´s:

[image]

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Thats a PHP error! So the compiler thinks thats code and not a parameter to pass

Comment: Are you sure that error is coming from this code?

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for your response. yes, from my query, it´s my unique call in this moment. In my count() it´s my error

Comment: @RiggsFolly i don´t know very well if my query it´s correct althought

Comment: @RiggsFolly debugMessage: "User Error: expected iterable, but did not find one for field Query.actividadesByAplicacionConEmpresas."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253151/discussion-between-scorpions78-and-riggsfolly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the SUM, COUNT, AVG and other SQL functions as text to the Eloquent translator. This is called "raw SQL". It's important to know that you're responsible for the syntax correctness of SQL commands passed in this form!

In your original code, you told PHP to pass the character count of a string (`'censosEmpresas.empresa_cif'`) to the "select" function, using the PHP `count()` function.

However, what you need to pass to the function is a text string indicating the number of rows in the `censosEmpresas.empresa_cif` column. The `select()` function is not suitable for this, because if you use `select("count(censosEmpresas.empresa_cif)")`, you would immediately get an error message saying that the column named `count(censosEmpresas.empresa_cif)` cannot be found.

Instead, you need to pass the calculation request in RAW SQL format: `selectRaw("count(censosEmpresas.empresa_cif)")`. This way, the Eloquent will literally insert `count(censosEmpresas.empresa_cif)` after the select keyword, and when the SQL is executed, you'll get the result back.

More information: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#selectraw

Example:

```php
Model::selectRaw("count(censosEmpresas.empresa_cif)");
```

Rewriting your original code:

```php
public function actividadesPorAplicacionConEmpresasCount($root, array $args, $context, $info)
{
    $actividadId = $args["aplicacion_id"];
    //$countEmpresas = CensosEmpresas::groupBy('empresa_cif')->select('codigoCenso', \DB::raw('count(*) as totalEmpresas'))->where('codigoCenso', $aplicacionId)->get();
    $countEmpresas = Actividad::selectRaw("count(censosEmpresas.empresa_cif)")
                                ->leftJoin('censos', 'id', 'actividades.censo_id')
                                ->leftJoin('censosEmpresas', 'id', 'censosEmpresas.codigoCenso')
                                ->where('censosEmpresas.codigoCenso', $actividadId)
                                ->groupBy('codigoCenso');

    return $countEmpresas;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. but return error debugMessage: "User Error: expected iterable, but did not find one for field Query.actividadesByAplicacionConEmpresas." my error has change

Comment: The 'leftJoin' requires both columns to be correctly defined.

First:
`->leftJoin('censos', 'censos.id', 'actividades.censo_id')`
`->leftJoin('censosEmpresas', 'censos.condigo', 'censosEmpresas.codigoCenso')`

Comment: thanks for your response. i have same result. i tryed with this code before you said it me

Comment: If you want to retrieve not only the Eloquent model as a result, you need to request the executed SQL result with the `get()` function.